# Get value from another HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to send the value of input element when user clicks on the button. What is the best way to accomplish this in Angular2?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for images..." />
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button (click)="onClick($event)" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
</span>
```

Comment: You need to "send it"? Where do you need to send it? :)

Comment: I need to send it to the onClick function...I got it working using NgModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can define refference to input using `#name` then you can use it `name.value`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for images..." #inputElement />
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button (click)="onClick($event, inputElement.value)" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
</span>
```

Its not the best its the easiest i would say

Answer (score 0):

**you can bind the click function as:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" placeholder="Enter the name"  />
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button (click)="onClick(value)">Go!</button>
</span>
```

**on .ts file you have to create onClick function**

```
onClick(valueRecieved){
// do what you want
}
```